# Warning: ftp_login(): Not logged in. Working in FileZilla with Only use plain PHP (insecure) Encryption mode

Tags: php, ftp, filezilla

I need to connect to an FTP server with given `host`, `username` and `password` only. When I try this code:

```
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server, 21) or die("Couldn't connect to $ftp_server");

$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);
```

I get this **error message**:

```
PHP Warning:  ftp_login(): Not logged in. in /var/www/html/vendgto/app/Arifulhb/Command/Gto.php on line 82
PHP Stack trace:
PHP   1. {main}() /var/www/html/vendgto/index.php:0
PHP   2. Arifulhb\Command\Gto->transferToServer() /var/www/html/vendgto/index.php:26
PHP   3. ftp_login() /var/www/html/vendgto/app/Arifulhb/Command/Gto.php:82

Warning: ftp_login(): Not logged in. in /var/www/html/vendgto/app/Arifulhb/Command/Gto.php on line 82

Call Stack:
    0.0014     223184   1. {main}() /var/www/html/vendgto/index.php:0
    0.2718    3132328   2. Arifulhb\Command\Gto->transferToServer() /var/www/html/vendgto/index.php:26
    5.7247    3227584   3. ftp_login() /var/www/html/vendgto/app/Arifulhb/Command/Gto.php:82
```

**FileZilla** configuration below do the login without error, but if I choose any other *Encryption* method, I get error.

[image: FileZilla screenshot]

With **any other *Encryption* method**, I got this message in FileZilla.
[image]

What's wrong with my PHP code to log in?

Comment: Your code is ok, it just looks like you are using a wrong username/password. Do you have an access to server-side logs? Can you show us a log file for both connections? If not, can you capture the traffic using Wireshark (or similar tool)?

Comment: Thanks @MartinPrikryl.. checking that :)